# Directing precise to trusty repository

Tags: apt, repository

I have an installation of Ubuntu 12.04. I want to explore the possibility of installing trusty packages on it by replacing the repository list in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to 14.04 repositories. I know it probably sounds like a bad idea but nonetheless - will this work? Is it safe?

Comment: It not only sounds like a bad idea, **it is a bad idea**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll work but it's not that safe in terms of stability; you might end up with broken packages. However, you'd pretty much be doing an upgrade to 14.04 because, as soon as your system does the first software update, the 14.04 counterparts of all your installed 12.04 packages and applications will update to the newest version available by default, versions from 14.04, unless specified otherwise.

You might find it useful to know that an upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 can be done via live disk without overwriting all your data as a full system install used to. You now have the option to upgrade your existing installation.

Alternatively, you  could run the following command from a terminal to do the upgrade to 14.04 that way:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Also, there are some differences in the filesystem structure from 12.04 to 14.04 that can cause conflicts without performing a complete upgrade.